# I want to implement when I click google map, the map can answer me and jump to another activity

Tags: android, google-maps

I do it like this, but it happens nothing.

```
aMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }});

}
```

Comment: Insert a break point  Intent intent = new Intent(); and start debug see if onClick event is called or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `SecondActivity.class` in your manifest?
`<aplication android:name=".SecondActivity"/>`

Comment: Also are you trying to go directly from the map to the second activity or from a marker?

Comment: go directly from the map.I added the SecondActivity.class in manifest.Thank you

Comment: is it all working now?  If so Mark the answer as correct please. Thank you